# Ext js grid row transparent background

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, background

There are many ways of changing background to a grid row. 
Using a renderer or setting a separate css class. With both techniques I was able to change the background color but I was unable to make it transparent.

I tried different `CSS` techniques but nothing sems to work.

Example using renderer:

```
metaData.style = "background-color:transparent !important";
```

Any suggestions or ideas maybe?

Comment: And I repeat, got any code for us?  It'd be easier to help you diagnose your problem if we saw all of your code.  Ext JS adds a lot of CSS by itself, so it's not as simple as saying (or maybe it is) it's a certain issue.  But you asked an Ext JS question, and I'd expect Ext JS code.

Comment: try this : `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`

Comment: Oğuz Çelikdemir sorry but your proposal make evrything gray and not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

try setting opacity separately.,

```
metaData.style = 'background-color:red !important; opacity: 0.50;';
```